# How to show the azure map route direction

Tags: azure-maps

I am showing the azure indoor map I am trying to show the azure map route direction .Is there any API/Example to show the route map direction .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indoor directions are not available for Azure Maps, but are coming soon.

If you are asking about outdoor routes, there is an open source project for creating nicely formatted route directions here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-services-ui